# Intro to EEG - Electroencephalography

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, eeg

Are there any introductory level text, researches or video for "How to learn EEG"?

Those material should include dictionary of terms, what waves mean, how to connect some activity in waves to brain activity... etc

There are lot of books which covered this subject, I am looking for something very basic and easy to comprehend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Practical approach to electroencephalography by Mark H. Libenson.
ISBN: 978-0-7506-7478-2

This should address your issues:

- dictionary of terms
- what waves mean
- how to connect some activity in waves to brain activity... etc

> Why consult encyclopedic references when you only need the essentials?
>   Practical Approach to Electroencephalography, by Mark H. Libenson, MD,
>   equips you with just the right amount of guidance you need for
>   obtaining optimal EEG results! It presents a thorough but readable
>   guide to EEGs, explaining what to do, what not to do, what to look
>   for, and how to interpret the results. It also goes beyond the
>   technical aspects of performing EEGs by providing case studies of the
>   neurologic disorders and conditions in which EEGs are used, making
>   this an excellent learning tool. Abundant EEG examples throughout help
>   you to recognize normal and abnormal EEGs in all situations.
>
> Presents enough detail and answers to questions and problems
>   encountered by the beginner and the non-expert. Uses abundant EEG
>   examples to help you recognize normal and abnormal EEGs in all
>   situations. Provides expert pearls from Dr. Libenson that guide you in
>   best practices in EEG testing. Features a user-friendly writing style
>   from a single author that makes learning easy. Examines the
>   performance of EEGs—along with the disorders for which they’re
>   performed—for a resource that considers the patient and not just the
>   technical aspects of EEGs. Includes discussions of various disease
>   entities, like epilepsy, in which EEGs are used, as well as other
>   special issues, to equip you to handle more cases.

Another review [here](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=nCGo1CkmBgYC&dq=Practical%20Approach%20to%20Electroencephalography&source=gbs_navlinks_s)

> Practical Approach to Electroencephalography differs from other EEG texts of its level in that it takes the time to explain itself, resulting in a far more readable albeit less portable text than other condensed introductory texts.

[Book Preview](http://www.neurology.org/content/76/7/e28.full)

This [link](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=nCGo1CkmBgYC&pg=PT7&lpg=PT7&dq=Practical%20Approach%20to%20Electroencephalography&source=bl&ots=OIk6eGc7f2&sig=L2wYOyk9rctTe9_JtMoM8b4xJT0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lHziUcGNFczxiAfLm4DQCQ&ved=0CFsQ6AEwBQ) will provide you with access to review the book yourself, before purchasing.